# Appcelerator IOS: Download a file and open it in another app

Tags: ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

What I want my app to do:
1.Download a .fmp12 file (filemaker database file) from my website
2.Open the file using Filemaker Go (so the database end up being saved in the FMGO data directory)

Possible or not ?
If possible, how do I do that ?
I can download the file but I don't know how to open it in filemaker go.

Comment: the UIDocumentInteractionController object allow you to open a file in another app 

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/index.html

Comment: Thanks. The Titanium implementation is Titanium.UI.iOS.DocumentViewer and I got it to work in a way. I created a document viewer for the downloaded file and used the show method.A "Sharing" window appears that let me chose the "Copy to Filemaker Go" option. It works fine but I don't want any user interaction. I want to download the file and open it in FMGo. Any idea on how to skip the share window and share to a specific app by code ?

Answer (score 0):

I've never done it myself , but there might be a way.

I wanted to do something like that at a time but in the end I choose something else.
Those links might help you :
inter-App communication   https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html
App groups ( you must allow them in your app capabilities) 
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html

I hope it helps .

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest you can get on Titanium is using Mads Moller's TiSocial module: https://github.com/viezel/TiSocial.Framework

Comment: I checked it a bit and it basically uses the url schemes of different apps to share directly to them. That's what I'm actually trying to do with the fmp:// url. The problem I have is to pass the filepath of the downloaded file to the fmp url. I tried many different format without success. Something like Titanium.Platform.openURL("fmp://"+Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory+"test.fmp12"). FmGO is launched but it can not find the file. The file has been saved under this name and is there. Not sure if what I'm trying to do is possible this way.

Comment: That's not what TiSocial does. It wraps the iOS UIActivityViewController, the common share dialog in iOS. Apps will surface that can share the type of file you pass automatically. See this part of the README: https://github.com/viezel/TiSocial.Framework#uiactivityviewcontroller

Comment: I will take another look at it.